# hover the sidebar vertical menu display a submenu in bootstrap material design

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to make a display of three columns as one submenu while hovering each menu.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <ul class="vertical-nav">
        <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link 2</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Sub Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Link 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to make the menu like this below image

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f38l7.jpg]

Answer (score 1):

Please see below. Hope this helps.

```js
$('.vertical-nav li a').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.sub-menu').show();
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.sub-menu').hide();
  });
```

```css
.sub-menu {
  display:none;
}
.vertical-nav li, .sub-menu li {
  list-style:none;
}
.column {
  float:left;
  width: 100px;
}
.title {
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <ul class="vertical-nav">
        <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link 2</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <div class='column'>
              <li class='title'>Style</li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Link 2</a></li>
            </div>
             <div class='column'>
              <li class='title'>Subject</li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Link 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Link 4</a></li>
            </div>
             <div class='column'>
              <li class='title'>Medium</li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Link 5</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Link 6</a></li>
            </div>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hello sir, thank you for your help, but there is some imperfection, as i am a beginner, i couldn't find it out. please see the image which i given above